# How to Activity Access Levels work in SF. When you set "Controlled by Parent" to Activities

Tags: event, sharing-rule

I have imported 2 organizations(Account(type- abc, xyz) & events) data into one production organization.And created two users (salesforce platform license) called A, B and set the OWD is priavte for account and control by parent for activities objects and created sharing rules for assigning abc acocunts to User A (READ/WRITE) and xyz accounts to User B (READ/WRITE). User A seeing only "abc" type of accounts with read/write access and events(read/write) associated with abc accounts, it's working fine.

Problem: User A also seeing Events(read access) associated with "xyz" type of accounts on calendar when he logged in salesforce. User A must see only "abc" events not "xyz". How to solve this issue.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Eduard: I set the activities is "Control by parent" not event.

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix the issue? Please let me know.

Comment: Does User A has Read access (record level) to "xyz" accounts?

Answer (score 3):

The most probable answer to you issue might be how Activity Access Levels work in SF. When you set "Controlled by Parent" to Activities it [**means**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_model_fields.htm&type=5):

> A user can perform an action (such as view, edit, transfer, and
>   delete) on an activity based on whether he or she can perform that
>   same action on the records associated with the activity.
>
> For example, if a task is associated with the Acme account and the
>   John Smith contact, then a user can only edit that task if he or she
>   can also edit the Acme account and the John Smith record.

For you it means that User A has read access to "xyz" accounts thus making its related Activities (Events) visible to the user. The only resort for you in this case would be making OWD for accounts Private (which you did) and remove all Sharing Rules for Account that grant User A access to that accounts.

Comment: User A doesn't have 'xyz' account access but still he is accessing events with read access associated with 'xyz' account.

Comment: Could you please update your question and attach screenshots with all these details (OWD, Shraing Rules for Accounts etc.). It also might be the case when user A can see user B, and user be has access to the 'xyz' events. So user A can see 'xyz' events too (see the excerpt from the docs above).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Currently User A accessing User B.  Any way we can fix the issue? Please let me know.